# How to keep correct styles in React-PDF with instance or PDFViewer?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I am using React-PDF (https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf). When I display the PDF simply with `<Document>`, the styles display correctly. For example, the bold here will appear correctly in the browser:

```
<Document>
    <Page size="A4">
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            This is bold
        </Text>
    </Page>
</Document>
```

However, as soon as a wrap this in `<PDFViewer>` for the iframe, the text is no longer bold. Similarly, if I try download the instance like this:

```
const [instance, updateInstance] = usePDF({ document: <ComponentOfAboveDocument /> });

 const handleExportFile = (instance) => {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = instance.url;
    // etc
 };
```

The bold fontWeight will not be present in the pdf, and similarly for other css properties which are listed as valid by React-PDF and do appear fine in the original `<Document>`.

Grateful for any advice!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue! The solution I found was to change the font family to the bold variant.

In my case, I was using `page: { fontFamily: 'Helvetica' }` for the page styles. For the header component that I wanted bold, I used `header: { fontFamily: 'Helvetica-Bold' }` and things worked as expected.